# Переключение классов

Tags: jquery

Для разметки, содержащей

```
<tr class="blackXX" />
<tr class="whiteXX" />
```

где X - это 0, 1... 9 нужно поменять blackXX на whiteXX, а whiteXX на blackXX. Какой это правильно реализовать в JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('tr[class*="black"]').each(function() {
    this.className = this.className.replace('black', 'white');  
});
```

Например, вот так.

**Дополнение**. Чуть-чуть погорячился вчера. Такой вариант заменит все вхождения слова «black» в именах классов. Лучше вот так:

```
$('tr[class^="black"]').each(function() {
    this.className = this.className.replace(/^black(\d+)$/, 'white$1');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Привет.
Попробуйте сделать так, если конечно я правильно вас понял).

```
var $blacks = $('.blackXX');
var $whites = $(".whiteXX");
$blacks.attr("class", "whiteXX");
$whites.attr("class", "blackXX");
```

**Дополнение.**

Может тогда на все эти элементы ещё довесить допустим классы black и white. И потом написать всё-таки в цикле, но немножко в другом стиле, пример:

```
$('.white').each(function(){
  var $element = $(this);
  var number=$element.attr("class").replace('white', '');
  $('.black' + number).attr("class", "white white" + number);
  $element.attr("class", "black black" + number);
});
```

Надо проверить будет ли работать, просто в блокноте набросал.

Comment: Спасибо. Это правильное решение, если ХХ неизменяемые величины. Сложность в том, что XX - это цифры. Поэтому есть много разных классов, например, black01, white12 и т.д. Можно, конечно, перебрать их все в цикле, но это как-то не компактно и не в стиле JQuery.

Comment: @Alexander Korsak Правильнее дополнить ответ, вместо создания нового: это в большей степени соответствует формату форума.

Comment: @ХэшКод спасибо большое, буду знать, впервые у вас на форуме :)